# How to Play Audio and remove file in QMediaPlayer?

Tags: qt, audio-streaming, qmediaplayer

I'm using qt5.0. I created dll and put all my audio files inside dll. now i am creating file from resource and playing. it's working fine.

But the problem is after playing the file I'm not able to delete that file and recreate new file.

if I try to delete manually also I getting error. "some other program using that file". once i stop the program then only able to delete the file.

How to delete the file after immediate palyback. here my code

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
connect(player,SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),this,SLOT(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));

QFile file2(QDir::tempPath() + "/temp0.mp3");

if (file2.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    QFile workFile(":/AUDIO/" + fn +".mp3");
    if(workFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
      file2.write(workFile.readAll());
      workFile.close();
    }

    file2.close();
}

player->setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::tempPath() + "/temp0.mp3")));
player->setVolume(100);
player->play();
```

---

```
void Audio::mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus state)
{
    if(state==QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia)
    {
        QFile::remove(QDir::tempPath() + "/temp0.mp3");
        qDebug()<<"Audio played";
    }
}
```

I'm getting "Audio played" message but it's not deleteing the file.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: is there any way directly stream from the DLL without creating any temp files?

Comment: It looks like the player may be keeping a handle to the file. If you delete the player object, can the file then be deleted?

Comment: well, i tried all the things but still i am getting error. so i put the audio files in the windows/media folder and using in the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Recently,I met the same problem.
I solved it by changing the compiler from msvs to mingw.
I think the Qt guys did not solve this bug as its status is 'need more information'. The code to release media file could be as follows.

```
player->setMedia(QMediaContent());
```

However, if I use mingw compiler, the video does not play in a VM win7 x86 and reports `DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040266`. This seems a deadlock to me.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html#media-prop) tell us for QMediaPlayer::setMedia:

> Setting this property to a null QMediaContent will cause the player to
>   discard all information relating to the current media source and to
>   cease all I/O operations related to that media.

Unfortunately this does not work on Windows 7 with Qt 5.1.1 - This why I filed a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34725)

Even the folks in the Qt irc channel told me not use QMediaPlayer on Windows. They suggested using SDL. Little bit strange for a cross platform framework with a Multimedia API.

Comment: I realize this is an old question.  In Python on Windows 10 and the file is a video file, `player.setMedia(QMediaContent(None))` releases the file and then the file can be deleted with `os.remove(temp0.mp4)`.  I have not tried this with an audio file, but I don't know why it would be any different.